# Will React-native be compatible with IOS 10?

Tags: ios, react-native, compatibility, ios10

It's not long now until ***IOS10*** is released. Those developing with React-native will want to know if it's *compatible* or *not*! I'm wanting to **upgrade** my *iPhone*, but I'm worried if I do, I won't be able to test my ***React-native*** apps on it.

Will there be compatibility issues? Will the RN community try compensate for older IOS versions as well as IOS 10? Any information would be helpful!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this ticket](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8344), iOS 10 support will be provided with RN 0.29

> The commit purported to provide iOS 10 support is slated to be
>   released with version 0.29:

Comment: Interesting! I thought it may have been a big deal to give support to a new IOS version

Comment: With Facebook using React Native for [its apps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/showcase.html), I guess they'll keep up with newer versions of iOS and Android.